# I have to manually reload the war file in Tomcat's webapps everytime I change something. How can I do it automatically?

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, war, netbeans-8.2

Title says it all. Everytime I make a change to my project (imported from GIT), I need to go into webapps, delete the old War file, and put the new one compiled by Netbeans. It's obviously exhausting, and I'm clearly doing something wrong. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have your tomcat server configured in the server tab in netbeans?

Comment: yep. @Dinnerspy

Comment: What version are you running of netbeans? I know in 8.2 you are able to deploy when pressing the run button not sure if later versions have it as they removed a lot of functionality from them.

Comment: It is netbeans 8.2. It does deploy when run, but it creates the WAR file in the project folder, and doesn't update the one in the appdata tomcat repository

Comment: Can you provide screen shots of what is happening so i can attempt to replicate?

Comment: Like is the wepage not updating with the changes? as sometimes you have to click the run button twice to get changes to take effect.

Comment: @Dinnerspy thanks a lot for the help! but I'm not sure what I should screenshot? the repositories? Basically when I run the application the war file is generated in the netbeans project folder. But the tomcat repository keeps the old one. So I have to manually change them. Want a screenshot of that?

EDIT: Exactly, I can not see the changes until i manually change them

Comment: Ok make a change then click the run button wait a few then click it again and the changes should show up. that happens for my webapps on tomcat as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. :( I probably have some problems in my configuration or something.

Comment: Dose your user netbeans is using have manage access? Do you have [autodeploy](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html) enabled?